# Standalone Script for Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking to locally use a Google Apps Script with one of my Google Sheets (Attached to a form) that will be accessible to all emails that have permission to access the sheet, but I don't plan on publishing this script to the public. Do I still need to publish in order to use this script, or will I be fine just adding an `onSubmit` function for my Google Form as a trigger for my script to run in my Google Sheet? And can I use installable triggers if I plan on operating this script as a standalone only attached to this one Google Sheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I still need to publish in order to use this script

**No:** If you own the spreadsheet (or have editor permissions on it), your script can remain private. A script does not need to be bound to a Spreadsheet except if it will use:

- Spreadsheet UI (`getUi()`, custom menus, dialogs and sidebars)
- "Active" items (`getActiveSpreadsheet()`, `getActiveSheet()`, `getActiveRange()`, `getActiveCell()`)

> ...will I be fine just adding an `onSubmit` function for my Google form as a trigger for my script to run in my Google Sheet?

**Yes:** Your standalone script can have installable triggers associated with Google Apps items such as spreadsheets, documents and forms.

> And can I use installable triggers if I plan on operating this script as a standalone only attached to this one Google Sheet?

**Yes:** There's nothing special about the 1:1 relationship; the same trigger could be installed for multiple spreadsheets.